# Dictionary for automated variable renaming

Tags: deobfuscation

I am working on a Java deobfuscation tool and one of the features I plan to implement is to automatically rename classes and methods with more memorable names. My plan is have a text file with a couple hundred possible names based on random distinctive English words. However, I am not sure where to get such a list.

I came across [this](http://search.cpan.org/~jjore/B-Deobfuscate-0.20/lib/B/Deobfuscate.pod) which does the same thing for Perl. However, it is not clear what dictionary it is using.

Does anyone have suggestions on the best way to obtain such a list? Ideally the words would all be distinctive and memorable and not clash with common programming keywords or terminology.

Comment: So you're going to transform each class or variable name into random dictionary words? Why? And why not just use a random string of characters?

Comment: The goal is to make the code easier to analyze for humans, and random strings are hard to keep track of. It's much easier to remember the difference between classes called, say, Parrot and Dawn then AAAB and AAAC.

Comment: Ohhhh... deobfuscation. Misread, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on unix you can try:

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words > words.txt
```

Else there is this [link](http://zyzzyva.net/wordlists.shtml)